# Map API data with this.state in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

How can I get the below **API** to display each `date` and `rate` from the **JSON** in a list? I have gone through the JSON and from what I can see I have mapped it correctly, yet `{this.state.calendarDay}` is undefined in the console, causing the `.map` to be undefined.

What am I missing?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Rates extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            fetched: false,
            isLoaded: false,
            calendarDay: []
        }
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        this.setState({
          loading : true
        });

        const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
        const url = `//apac.littlehotelier.com/api/v1/properties/chatelainevalleydirect/rates.json`;
        fetch(proxyurl + url).then(res => res.json())
        .then(res =>{
            this.setState({
                calendarDay : res.rate_plans,
                loading : true,
                fetched : true
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        const {fetched, loading, calendarDay} = this.state;
        let content;
        if(fetched){
          content =
          <ul>
            {calendarDay.rate_plan_dates.map((dailyRates,index) => <li key={index+1}>{dailyRates.date} - ${dailyRates.rate}</li>)}
          </ul>;
        }
        else if(loading && !fetched){
            content = <p> Loading ...</p>;
        }
        else{
          content = <div/>;
        }
        return (
          <div>
            {content}
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Rates;
```

Comment: Try to console.log(state.calendarDay) right after u `setState`?

Comment: Then share us the data for us to have a better picture

Comment: Thank you Issac, when `console.log(this.state.calendarDay)` is placed after `setState` I get `calendarDay` is `undefined. Cheers again for you help - any suggestions?

Comment: Response is array not object

Comment: Yes you are correct. Cheers @charlietfl.

Comment: @Darren, Is it resolved or you are still struggling ?

Comment: Hi @Infinity. Working through it but struggling to get the list working. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using nested array of objects. Here's a rough solution that I made.

```
this.setState({
            calendarDay : res, // change this
            loading : true,
            fetched : true
        });
```

inside the render function

```
if(fetched){
      content =
        <div>
            {calendarDay.map((item, k) =>
          <div key={k} >
            {item.rate_plans.map((ratePlans, ratePlanKey)=>
                <ul key={ratePlanKey}>
                    {ratePlans.rate_plan_dates.map((dailyRates,index) => <li key={index+1}>{dailyRates.date} - ${dailyRates.rate}</li>)}
                </ul>
            )}
          </div>
            )}
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Kamran. I'll accept the answer as it allows me. Wondering if you could also give a pointer in splitting the `return` by their `rate_plan`? Being `Varenna Luxury` and `Weekend Getaway`?

Comment: The `rate_plan` array contains 3 three items, inside them contains a `name` object. Do you want to split them based on the name object?

Comment: Yes that is correct - Basically I am needing to keep the first two and remove the third.

Comment: Again this is a very rough solution. I think this is what you're looking to do.

`{item.rate_plans.map((ratePlans, ratePlanKey)=>
             <div key={ratePlanKey} >
              {ratePlanKey<2 ?
              <ul>
               <h3>{ratePlans.name}</h3>
                {ratePlans.rate_plan_dates.map((dailyRates,index) => <li key={index+1}>{dailyRates.date} - ${dailyRates.rate}</li>)}
               </ul> : null
      }
             </div>
         )}`

Answer (score 0):

Couple of problems I see

First you specified that `calendarDay: []` is an array and at the same time you are mapping through its property which makes no sense

```
{calendarDay.rate_plan_dates.map...
```

So what it is currently looks like `array[].property` is always undefined.

Since `calendarDay` is an array so it will not have a direct property `rate_plans`.

one of your comments

> when **console.log(this.state.calendarDay)** is placed after setState I
>   get calendarDay is `undefined`. Cheers again for you help - any
>   suggestions?

if you put log immediately after setting up the state it will not work as expected because `state` in react works in asynchronous mode.

verify by the callback -

```
this.setState({
      calendarDay: res,
      loading: true,
      fetched: true
    }, () => console.log(this.state.calendarDay));
```

if 
it is still undefined then `res.rate_plans` is coming undefined from the server.

else do the followings as
**@Kamran Nazir** already mentioned in his answer.

```
{calendarDay.map((item, k) => <div key={k}>
            {item
              .rate_plans
              .map((ratePlans, ratePlanKey) => <ul key={ratePlanKey}>
                {ratePlans
                  .rate_plan_dates
                  .map((dailyRates, index) => <li key={index + 1}>{dailyRates.date}
                    - ${dailyRates.rate}</li>)}
              </ul>)}
          </div>)}
```

Comment: Thank you Infinity. Great response - think you have just cleared up a common mistake I tend to make.

Comment: @Darren, That is great

Answer (score 0):

Call the api in ComponentDidMount and also I have split the code based on plan name.Hope this helps.

```
class Rates extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        loading: false,
        calendarDay: []
    }
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({
      loading : true
    });
            var self = this;
    const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
    const url = `//apac.littlehotelier.com/api/v1/properties/chatelainevalleydirect/rates.json`;
    fetch(proxyurl + url).then(res => res.json())
    .then(res =>{
     console.log(res)
        self.setState({
            calendarDay : res,
            loading : false,
        });
    });
}

render() {

    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.loading &&
            <p>Loading...</p>
        }
        {(this.state.calendarDay.length == 0 && !this.state.loading) && 
            <p>No data Available</p>
        }
        {this.state.calendarDay.length > 0 &&
            <ul>
            {this.state.calendarDay.map(function(i,index){
                return(
                <li key={index}>
                {i.rate_plans.map(function(j,index){
                  return(
                    <ul key={index}> <p>{j.name}</p>
                      {j.rate_plan_dates.map(function(dailyRates,index){
                          return(
                            <li key={index+1}>{dailyRates.date} - ${dailyRates.rate}</li>
                        )
                      })}
                    </ul>
                  )
                })}
                </li>
                )
          })
            }
          </ul>
        }
      </div>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Cheers. I like your solution - It explains a lot of queries I was having.

Comment: @Darren Great !